# Toggle of header-bar

Tags: jquery, iframe, toggle

I have problem with my website, I want to do toggle exactly like this example:

```
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/36298.html
```

I have top bar (width 50px) include arrow toggle and in the rest of page I have iframe of website.

All I want to do is toggle animated effect - move top bar from absolute top 0 to absolute top -50 to hide and in the same time i want to change iframe height from 100%-50px to 100%.

I did this script and it works perfectly to hide top bar but not to show it again to default values.

http://jsfiddle.net/2WMtX/

Can you help me out? Thanks

Comment: can you post your html as well?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `live` instead of `click` ? live works for elements that doesn't exist at the time you define event listener and i guess that your `.show-bar` element doesn't exist at the start. try this:

```
$('#demo').height($(window).height()-50); // default iframe height

$(".hide-bar").live('click',function(){ // hide top bar
  $("#header-bar").animate({"top":"-50px"},300);
  $("#demo").animate({"height":$(window).height()-0},300);
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("show-bar");
});

$(".show-bar").live('click',function(){ // show top bar
  $("#header-bar").animate({"top":"0px"},300);
  $("#demo").animate({"height":$(window).height()-50},300);
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("hide-bar");
});
```

***NOTE:*** This will work for jquery v1.7 (in 1.9 method `live` was removed)

below is the same code for newer versions of jquery:

```
    $('#demo').height($(window).height()-50);

    $(document).on('click',".hide-bar",function(){
      $("#header-bar").animate({"top":"-50px"},300);
      $("#demo").animate({"height":$(window).height()},300);
      $(this).removeClass();
      $(this).addClass("show-bar");
    });

    $(document).on('click',".show-bar", function(){
      $("#header-bar").animate({"top":"0px"},300);
      $("#demo").animate({"height":$(window).height()-50},300);
      $(this).removeClass();
      $(this).addClass("hide-bar");
    });
```

Comment: could you paste your code into fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ ) so we can help you

Comment: i get it - live does'nt exist any more in jQuery 1.9 (i am still using 1.7 ;) : http://jsfiddle.net/UX6zk/6/

Comment: below previous code i added solution for jquery 1.9 ( http://jsfiddle.net/2yuMZ/1/ )

Answer (score 0):

I hope below solution can help you.

**css code:**

```
#header-bar {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:200px; background-color:grey; height:50px;}
#close-bar { position:absolute; bottom:-20px; background:red; color:white;}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<section id="header-bar" class="txt-highlight-color bg-color bg-pattern">
  <span id="close-bar" class="hide-bar">close button</span>
</section>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var speed = 300;
        $('#close-bar').on('click', function(){

            var $$ = $(this);

            if( $$.is('.hide-bar') ){
                $('#header-bar').animate({top:-50}, speed);
                $$.removeClass('hide-bar')
            } else {
                $('#header-bar').animate({top:0}, speed);
                $$.addClass('hide-bar')
            }

        });
```

Example Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yR8/

Comment: this is good solution, but in my css i have background-image for every  class (when top bar is hidden, it show image arrow down and when it is down, it show background image arrow up). can you add it please? thanks

Comment: you can simple toggle the classes in if condition. by this you can change the arrow up/down.

Answer (score 0):

OK GUYS I'VE GOT IT, HERE IS MY FINAL CODE:

```
$(function() {
  $('#demo').height($(window).height()-$("#header-bar").height());
  var speed = 300;
  $(document).on('click',".hide-bar",function(){
    $("#header-bar").animate({"top": - $("#header-bar").height()},speed);
    $("#demo").animate({"height":$(window).height()},speed);
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("show-bar");
  });

  $(document).on('click',".show-bar", function(){
    $("#header-bar").animate({"top":"0px"},speed);
    $("#demo").animate({"height":$(window).height()-$("#header-bar").height()},speed);
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("hide-bar");
  });
});
```

WITH THIS I CAN ONLY SET `#header-bar` width in CSSfile and it change it all

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP